# Getting mean of an image using a mask

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a series of concentric rectangles and wish to obtain the means of the outer rectangle **excluding** the inner rectangle. See the attached diagram , I need to get the mean for the shaded area.
[image]

So I am using a mask of the inner rectangle to pass into the `cv2.mean` method, but I am not sure how to set the mask. I have the following code:

```
for i in xrange(0,len(wins)-2,1):
    means_1 = cv2.mean(wins[i])[0]
    msk = cv2.bitwise_and(np.ones_like((wins[i+1]), np.uint8),np.zeros_like((wins[i]), np.uint8))
    means_2 = cv2.mean(wins[i+1],mask=msk)
    means_3 = cv2.mean(wins[i+1])[0]
    print means_1,means_2,means_3
```

I get this error for the `means_2` (`means_3` works fine).:

> error:
>   /Users/jenkins/miniconda/0/2.7/conda-bld/work/opencv-2.4.11/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:1021:
>   error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays
>   have the same size and type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op
>   array' in function binary_op

Comment: Do some debugging then. What are the sizes of the two arrays you pass to `bitwise_and`? (I assume that's where the error comes from, since you cut off the stack trace) If you don't provide a complete, reproducible example, noone can do that for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The mask here refers to a binary mask which has `0` as background and `255` as foreground, So You need to create an empty mask with default color = `0` and then paint the Region of Interest where you want to find the mean with `255`. Suppose I have input image [512 x 512]:

[image]

Lets's assume 2 concentric rectangles as:

```
outer_rect = [100, 100, 400, 400] # top, left, bottom, right
inner_rect = [200, 200, 300, 300]
```

Now create the binary mask using these rectangles as:

```
mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.rectangle(mask, (outer_rect[0], outer_rect[1]), (outer_rect[2], outer_rect[3]), 255, -1)
cv2.rectangle(mask, (inner_rect[0], inner_rect[1]), (inner_rect[2], inner_rect[3]), 0, -1)
```

[image]

Now you may call the `cv2.mean()` to get the mean of foreground area, labelled with `255` as:

```
lena_mean = cv2.mean(image, mask)
>>> (109.98813432835821, 96.60768656716418, 173.57567164179105, 0.0)
```

Comment: The question was specifically regarding a mask, but it is worth noting that (based on my testing) using submats (ROI, a rectangular part of the original input) yield far better results performance wise (like multiple times better on high resolutions).

Comment: for newer numpy version (like 1.16) see masked arrays: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#maskedarray-generic-constructing

Answer (score 2):

In Python/OpenCV or any software, if you have a masked image and the binary mask, then the mean of the non-black pixels in the image (i.e. ROI) is the mean of the masked image divided by the mean of the mask

Input:

[image]

Mask:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image 
img = cv2.imread('lena_g.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# load mask
mask = cv2.imread('lena_mask.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# compute means
mean_img = np.mean(img)
mean_mask = np.mean(mask)

# compute 255*mean_img/mean_mask
mean_roi = 255 * mean_img / mean_mask

# print mean of each
print("mean of image:", mean_img)
print("mean of mask:", mean_mask)
print("mean of roi:", mean_roi)
```

```
mean of image: 98.50196838378906
mean of mask: 216.090087890625
mean of roi: 116.23856597522328
```